# SQL Server FileStream - How to acquire files path

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, filestream, sqlfilestream

I'm working on this application where I need to upload large data files to my SQL Server DB, and I've been using FileStream to do it more efficiently.

I understand the files are stored directly into my system's folders (C:\CryptoDB).

The thing is, I need to manipulate these files (decrypt them) but I haven't been able to recover their filepath. 
Doing so, I would be able to manipulate them directly, not having to re-download them via SQL, which is a real waste.

What I've been able to do so far:

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE [arquivo] (
[idUsuario]   INT NOT NULL,
[fileState]   INT NOT NULL,
[fileContent] varbinary(max) FILESTREAM,
[fileName]    VARCHAR (150)   NULL,
[fileSize]    VARCHAR (50)    NULL,

id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE,

CONSTRAINT [FK_arquivo_usuario] FOREIGN KEY ([idUsuario]) REFERENCES usuario(id)
);
```

Insert:

```
Insert into arquivo(id, idUsuario, fileState, fileContent, fileName, fileSize) Values(
newId(),
1,
5,
(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\medio.jpeg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS varbinary(max)) ,
'medio.jpeg',
'123'
)
```

And when I try to recover the filepath:

```
DECLARE @filePath varchar(max)

SELECT @filePath = fileContent.PathName()
FROM arquivo

PRINT @filepath
```

The result I get:

```
\\TEHORT-PC\MSSQLSERVER\v02-A60EC2F8-2B24-11DF-9CC3-AF2E56D89593\CryptoDB\dbo\arquivo\fileContent\31E3697E-0576-4B0F-B0AA-6E046F4116A1\VolumeHint-HarddiskVolume2
```

Where the file actually is:

```
C:\CryptoDB\DATA\902a7d8d-c8c1-43b0-8c94-b12319293f42\7febdbd1-02c6-4b00-aa3c-a72bee80ef9c\
```

Answer (score 1):

1. SQL query for get physical location of all FILESTREAM data ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24636952/5134939))

   SELECT      t.name AS 'table',
               c.name AS 'column', 
               fg.name AS 'filegroup_name', 
               dbf.type_desc AS 'type_description',
               dbf.physical_name AS 'physical_location'
   FROM        sys.filegroups fg
   INNER JOIN  sys.database_files dbf
   ON          fg.data_space_id = dbf.data_space_id
   INNER JOIN  sys.tables t
   ON          fg.data_space_id = t.filestream_data_space_id
   INNER JOIN  sys.columns c
   ON          t.object_id = c.object_id
   AND         c.is_filestream = 1

[All FILESTREAM BLOB-fields query result sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXXf9.png)

2. SQL query for get subfolders for FILESTREAM data on server:
   ***(These tables only used within dedicated Administrator connection (DAC)).***

   SELECT o.name AS [Table], cp.name AS [Column], r.rsguid AS [Rowset GUID], rs.colguid AS [Column GUID] FROM SYS.SYSROWSETS r CROSS APPLY sys.sysrscols rs
   JOIN sys.partitions p ON rs.rsid = p.partition_id
   JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = p.object_id
   JOIN sys.syscolpars cp ON cp.colid = rs.rscolid
   WHERE rs.colguid IS NOT NULL AND o.object_id = cp.id AND r.rsguid IS NOT NULL AND r.rowsetid = rs.rsid AND o.name = 'DOCUMENT' and cp.name = 'DIGITAL_FILE';

2.1. Query result:

> **Table:** DOCUMENT
>   **Column:** DIGITAL_FILE
>   **Rowset GUID:** 0x6AA5E6045794D34D8B1FAC0F49A49B0A
>   **Column GUID:** 0xD756E638FB2CC843AE98F489B57F6D7D

Calculating Sub-Path from this guids:

> 0x6AA5E6045794D34D8B1FAC0F49A49B0A equals this path:
>   04e6a56a-9457-4dd3-8b1f-ac0f49a49b0a
>
> **[reversed 6AA5E604]-[reversed 5794]-[reversed D34D]-[reversed 8B1F]-[original AC0F49A49B0A]**
>
> 0xD756E638FB2CC843AE98F489B57F6D7D equals this path:
>   38e656d7-2cfb-43c8-ae98-f489b57f6d7d (rules in previus guid parsing)

2.2 Result calculated full path for FILESTREAM storage:

> i:\SQL Base posc_astrachan FileStreams\GTMK\GTM_FILE_STREAM\04e6a56a-9457-4dd3-8b1f-ac0f49a49b0a\38e656d7-2cfb-43c8-ae98-f489b57f6d7d

3. Get original filename for BLOB-value in NTFS-folder.

3.1. Stored procedure for query advanced SQL Server Page info

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procDBCC_PAGE]
    @db_name varchar (500),
    @filenum INT,
    @pagenum INT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON 
DBCC TRACEON (3604);
DBCC PAGE (@db_name, @filenum, @pagenum, 3) WITH TABLERESULTS;
SET NOCOUNT OFF     
END
```

3.2. Stored procedure for query original filename for FILESTREAM'ed BLOB-field of table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[procFindLogSequenceNumber] 
-- @TableName varchar (500),
 @instanceS varchar (19), -- key value for filed INSTANCE_S
 @tableName varchar(500), -- DOCUMENT
 @keyFieldName varchar(500), -- INSTANCE_S
 @LogSequenceNumber varchar (500) OUTPUT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @db_name varchar (500) 
DECLARE @filenum INT
DECLARE @pagenum INT
DECLARE @slotnum INT
DECLARE @rid varchar (100) 
DECLARE @ridDotted varchar (100) 

DECLARE @parent_object varchar (500)

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000)
DECLARE @sqlTable Table(physloc varchar(100))

DECLARE @DBCC_PAGE_Output Table ([ParentObject] varchar (MAX), [Object] varchar (MAX), [Field] varchar (MAX), [VALUE] varchar (MAX))

SET @db_name = db_name()

SET @sql = 'SELECT top 1 sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter (%%physloc%%) AS [PhysicalRID] FROM '+@tableName+' WHERE '
             +@keyFieldName+' = '''+@instanceS+''''

INSERT @sqlTable (physloc)
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

SET @rid = (select top 1 physloc from @sqlTable)
if @rid is NULL
BEGIN
  RETURN -1;
END

-- parse (@rid): (1:1172779:6)  1-@filenum, 2- @pagenum, 3- @slotnum 
SET @ridDotted = Replace(@rid, ':', '.');
SET @ridDotted = Replace(@ridDotted, '(', '');
SET @ridDotted = Replace(@ridDotted, ')', '');

SET @filenum = (SELECT Parsename(@ridDotted, 3))
SET @pagenum = (SELECT Parsename(@ridDotted, 2))
SET @slotnum = (SELECT Parsename(@ridDotted, 1))

INSERT @DBCC_PAGE_Output ([ParentObject], [Object], [Field], [VALUE]) 
EXECUTE procDBCC_PAGE @db_name, @filenum , @pagenum

SET @parent_object = (SELECT TOP 1 [ParentObject] FROM @DBCC_PAGE_Output WHERE [Field] = 'INSTANCE_S'
 AND [VALUE] = @instanceS) 

--CreateLSN field Only
SET @LogSequenceNumber = (SELECT [VALUE] FROM  @DBCC_PAGE_Output WHERE 
 [ParentObject] = @parent_object AND
 [Field] = 'CreateLSN'
)

if @LogSequenceNumber is NULL
BEGIN
  RETURN -1;
END

-- result 0006c050:00000120:0090 (442448:288:144)
-- clear (...)
SET @LogSequenceNumber = Replace(@LogSequenceNumber, ' ', '.');
SET @LogSequenceNumber = (SELECT Parsename(@LogSequenceNumber, 2))

--replace ":" to "-"
SET @LogSequenceNumber = Replace(@LogSequenceNumber, ':', '-');

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

3.3. Sample query for stored procedure for get filename on NTFS folder for BLOB:

```
declare @filestreamFileName varchar(500);
exec procFindLogSequenceNumber 'ZW_NU9hGZ0CKoSXYAoc', 'DOCUMENT', 'INSTANCE_S', @filestreamFileName OUTPUT
select @filestreamFileName
```

3.4. Result (original file name in NTFS folder):

> 0003137a-00001244-00d0

3.5. Result full path:

> i:\SQL Base posc_astrachan FileStreams\GTMK\GTM_FILE_STREAM\04e6a56a-9457-4dd3-8b1f-ac0f49a49b0a\38e656d7-2cfb-43c8-ae98-f489b57f6d7d\0003137a-00001244-00d0

Answer (score 0):

The path you get is correct, you are supposed to get the network share path not the local path and use SqlFileStream to open a stream.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You could also get a file handle using OpenSqlFilestream method, i.e. to use it in Windows API.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933972.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Alexander's answer is great, saved me a LOT of trouble correlating page/slot numbers to actual *LSNs*. In my case using SQL Server 2008 R2 I had to make some adjustments to his SP to get it working, those were:

The **SPs first parameter:**

> @instanceS varchar **(100)**, -- key value for filed INSTANCE_S

In my case this is a uniqueidentifier so I needed a bigger varchar, original value was 19.

When **querying DBCC PAGE Output:**

> SET @parent_object = (SELECT TOP 1 [ParentObject] FROM
>   @DBCC_PAGE_Output WHERE **[Field] = @keyFieldName**  AND [VALUE] =
>   @instanceS)

It originaly stated `"[Field] = 'INSTANCE_S'"` which apparently hardcoded a value that worked for OP but not for me. It needed to match the name of the FILESTREAM table's key field.

Also to clarify the **SPs input params** a bit:

> @instanceS = The actual column value which identifies the row. Will
>   this always match the column set as the table's "RowGuid"?
>   @tableName = Pretty clear. The FILESTREAM table's name.
>   @keyFieldName = The name of the table's key column. Should be the
>   source column from where @instanceS was taken.