# SQL Server: Trace Flag 5556 What is it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, dbcc

I have run tracestatus on our production server and found that 5556 trace flag is on.

[image: dbcc results]

I have searched web and docs but could not find what is it. Does anyone knows what is it for?

Version : Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) with file stream ON.

Comment: This question isn't related to programming. I suggest you ask on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server. Note that some traceflags are entirely undocumented and may have been recommended by Microsoft support.

Comment: Trace Flag 5556 is used for FileStream.. see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183029/physical-location-of-filestream-data) HTH